# Joining two tables based on their dates without primary keys(SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am lost here

I have two tables

This is the Period Table

[image]

And the Days Table

[image]

Days table counts the days of an employee when he went on a vacation

Period table is a temporary table created from a lot of if else statements

What I want to do is to join Days table with the Period table grouped by their years (and possibly use aggregate functions)

----EDIT----
Here is the query for Days Table

```
Select COUNT(isMandatory) + COUNT(isVacation) as 'Mandatory/Sick', COUNT(isSick) as Sick, 
YEAR (date) as 'Year' from datesInclusiveTable where leaveID in 
(select leaveID from leaveTable where acctNo = 'M29076')
Group by YEAR (date)
```

You see it has aggregate functions

I would like to post the query for Period Table but it's too long and might be

too complicated to look at

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the first answer (I don't know how to tag the user), but I need to convert my Days table first into a temporary table (because it is filled with aggregate functions) and inner join doesn't seem to work with tables that has aggregate functions, so now I'm stuck with trying to convert Year to a date data type so it wouldn't conflict with the Period Table's data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DateStarted (or DateEnded) are of data type date:

```
SELECT * FROM Days D
INNER JOIN Period P ON YEAR(P.DateStarted) = D.Year
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm currently trying to transfer the Days table into a temporary table because it has aggregate functions and Inner join won't allow joining tables when there are aggregate functions, I'll reply back after I figure out how to handle the year column's data type

Comment: I was able to transfer Days Table to a temporary table and it works, but I had to use left join, thank you. I didn't know YEAR(P.DateStarted) can be used in a join condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Days D
JOIN Period P ON YEAR(CONVERT(date, P.DateStarted)) = D.Year;
```